# Cannot Center Button in tablerow

Tags: android

Im trying to center a `button` in a tablerow but its not working. My `main.xml` file is bellow.I have tried this but it is not working:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow >        
            <TextView
                android:text="Enter your details below:"
                />
        </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView              
            android:text="Name"     
            />
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/txtname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"       
                   />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
         <TextView
             android:text="Email Address"     
            />
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/txtemail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                   />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
         <TextView              
            android:text="Phone Number"     
            />
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:inputType="phone"
                   />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow >    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:gravity="center"
             />        
       </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

List item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow >
        <TextView
            android:text="Enter your details below:"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Email Address"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtemail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Phone Number"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `gravity` for the `Button`:

```
android:gravity="center"
```